# Basic nginx proxy_pass fails with HTTP 500

Tags: nginx

I have an extremely minimal configuration that I believe should reverse proxy what I see on `example.com:1234` to `example.com[:80]`.

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

events{
}

http{
    server{
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://example.com:1234;
            proxy_redirect default;
        }
    }
}
```

However, navigating to port 80 results in an internal server error `500` - while navigating to port `1234` renders the expected output.

The log contains only "signal process started" entries.

What have I done wrong, or missed? How can I log a better (any!) description of the server error; I anticipate this is not the last time that would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

If your backend is on the same host try using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;` instead `proxy_pass http://example.com:1234;`. NGINX invokes an internal name resolution logic before using DNS, since your `server_name` is the same as hostname in `proxy_pass` directive, this may be source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove proxy_redirect and send another request to the NGINX. If there is still Internal Server error investigate the log file.

Also, It will not harm if you check the backend (proxy_pass http://example.com) with curl from your server to getting sure your backend is healthy.